# Unable to build solution in VSTS pipeline

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am working on a service fabric solution and I am able to build and test the changes in my local machine whereas in VSTS pipeline and facing a minor issue saying that the interface method is not implemented.

If anyone of you face a similar issue, Can you guys suggest or help me out on how to fix or resolve this issue in the build pipeline.

Here is my scenario.

**Interface**

```
public interface IStudent
{
    void PrintFullName();
}
```

**Base Class**

```
public class BaseStudent
{
    public void PrintFullName()
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

**MainClass**

```
public class Student : BaseStudent, IStudent
{
    public void PrintName()
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: `Student` requires `new` (or `virtual`, `override`) on `PrintFullName` as it's already declared in `BaseStudent`; surprised it compiles locally.

Comment: What's the Visual Studio version you're using and what's the one on Azure Devops in your build pipeline?

Comment: @sellotape , Please check the updated question.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, I am using VS 17 in build pipeline and locally.

Comment: Show us the build pipeline or yaml, whatever you have

Comment: the setup you descripe works well. however when i setup a solution with 3 assemblies (one for each element) i got the error you mentioned locally when i hadn't yet added all neccessairy using-statements. check if you have all references you need and check your using-statements